# Determine logged on user on Windows computer from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, samba

How can I determine who is logged on to a remote Windows XP computer from Linux?  I do not have administrator access on the domain or on the remote computer.

I can do it from a separate Windows computer using `PsLoggedOn -L \\computer` from [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx)

I've tried using `nmblookup -A remotecomputer`, but I only see entries for the 
computer and the domain, not a `<03>` entry for the user.

I've also tried running PsLoggedOn under wine; I get an error:

```
Connecting to Registry of \\computer.company.com...
fixme:reg:RegConnectRegistryW Connect to L"computer.company.com" is not supported.
```

I started looking into [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/), but it looks like I would need administrative rights on the remote computer to get it working.

Comment: With your current answer, How can you determine which of the HKEY_USERS of the computer are currently logged on ? I tried on my network with an AD, but the `net rpc registry` command doesn't give me a correct output : Keyname = d__(+ Classname = Modtime = Thu, 12 Oct 4461634 12:03:12 CET This is all the output I have.

Comment: I don't know enough about the `net rpc registry` command to speculate why it would give such garbage output...  I recommend you start a new question about it.

Comment: I've found the problem. Red Hat linux, with an old hidden in the forest samba `net` tool which doesn't work with our AD/network/windows. I tested on a VirtualBox with ubuntu 12.04, and the net rpc registry works just fine.
Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how to do this using Samba on the Linux computer.

I installed and configured Kerberos and Samba to access the domain.  I modified `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, `/etc/krb5.conf`, and `/etc/hosts`.  I then used some `net` commands from a script (`net` is a command-line interface to Samba):

```
net rpc registry enumerate 'HKEY_USERS' -S xpcomputer.ad.company.com -U 'username@AD.COMPANY.COM%password'
```

giving a list of the [security identifiers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330) for the users that are currently loaded in the registry:

```
Keyname   = .DEFAULT
Modtime   = Thu, 02 Dec 2010 14:31:14 EST

Keyname   = S-1-5-19
Modtime   = Thu, 02 Dec 2010 14:31:16 EST

Keyname   = S-1-5-19_Classes
Modtime   = Thu, 02 Dec 2010 14:31:16 EST

Keyname   = S-1-5-20
Modtime   = Thu, 02 Dec 2010 14:31:16 EST

Keyname   = S-1-5-20_Classes
Modtime   = Thu, 02 Dec 2010 14:31:16 EST

Keyname   = S-1-5-21-8915387-325552579-1798637320-4573
Modtime   = Fri, 03 Dec 2010 22:53:39 EST

Keyname   = S-1-5-21-8915387-325552579-1798637320-7772
Modtime   = Wed, 08 Dec 2010 07:51:26 EST

Keyname   = S-1-5-21-8915387-325552579-1798637320-7772_Classes
Modtime   = Wed, 08 Dec 2010 07:51:26 EST

Keyname   = S-1-5-18
Modtime   = Thu, 02 Dec 2010 14:31:14 EST
```

I then run the `net ads sid` command to lookup active directory entries based on the user SID.  This might only work for domain users; I'm not sure if it works for users logged on using a local account.  It seems that if there are multiple SIDs, the only one that works is the one that has a corresponding "_Classes" entry.

```
net ads sid 'S-1-5-21-8915387-325552579-1798637320-7772' -W COMPANY -U 'username@AD.COMPANY.COM%password'
```

This gives some errors, but still results in printing the user's entire Active Directory information.  It is fairly slow, possibly due to the errors, so I might cache the SID-to-username mapping.

```
[2010/12/08 10:03:00,  0] libads/kerberos.c:882(create_local_private_krb5_conf_for_domain)
  create_local_private_krb5_conf_for_domain: smb_mkstemp failed, for file /var/run/samba/smb_tmp_krb5.HpBqKJ. Errno Permission denied
[2010/12/08 10:03:02,  0] libads/kerberos.c:882(create_local_private_krb5_conf_for_domain)
  create_local_private_krb5_conf_for_domain: smb_mkstemp failed, for file /var/run/samba/smb_tmp_krb5.BCzT0T. Errno Permission denied
Got 1 replies

objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: [Lastname], [Firstname]
sn: [Lastname]
c: US
physicalDeliveryOfficeName: ...
telephoneNumber: ...
...(many more  fields)...
mailNickname: FLastname
...
```

The mailNickname field contains the user name (at least for the users I have tested so far).

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while looking for a solution to the exact same problem. Staring with Justin's answer above I finally came up with this bit of Perl. $Comp is the name of the computer we wish to interrogate.

```
$Res = `/usr/bin/net rpc registry enumerate 'HKEY_USERS' -S $Comp -U 'user\@domain\%password' | /bin/grep _Classes`;
 # For this application we're only interested in one entry and don't care if there are more
$Res =~ /= (.+)_Classes/;
$Sid = $1;
$Res = `/usr/bin/net ads sid -W domain -I IP_address_of_DC -U 'user\@domain\%password' "$Sid"`;
$Res =~ /sAMAccountName: (.*)/;
$User = $1; # The user logon ID
$Res = `/usr/bin/net ads search "(sAMAccountName=$User)" -U 'user\@domain\%password'`;
$Res =~ /displayName: (.*)/;
# The user's display name, which is what we're after
$Name = $1;
```

If speed is an issue, as it was for Justin, check to ensure the realm and workgroup settings are correct in smb.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to install software on the remote computer?

If so, you can install the **Opsview agent**, (nagios client) from here: http://www.opsview.com/downloads/opsview-agents that will allow you to query any of the MS performance counters.

I'm not sure if logged on users is available as a performance counter, but if it is, then this could work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to install software on the remote computer.  It is very tightly controlled since it is used to interface with some specialized equipment.